# securing query authorization in linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have 3 tables: `the User table, the Records table and the UserRecords table`.

The columns are so:

```
UserTable
UserID | OtherUserDataFields

RecordsTable
RecordID | OtherRecordDataFields

UserRecords
UserID | RecordID
```

The UserRecords table tells me which users have authorization on which record. I have a function that updates the RecordsTable by receiving 2 paramaters: a record TheRecord (which contains a RecordID field) and a UserID.

I'm writing a query in the data context MyDC to fetch the record with the RecordID supplied in the parameter and test if the user is authorized on that record like this:

```
var RecordToUpdate = (
    from r in MyDC.RecordsTable
    from u in MyDC.UserRecords
    where r.RecordID == TheRecord.RecordID && TheRecord.RecordID == u.RecordID
    where u.UserID == TheUserID
    select r).SingleOrDefault();
```

Will this ensure me that only records the user is authorized will be fetched? I want to avoid cases where users maliciously send a record they're not authorized on and make changes to these unauthorized records.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: `&& u.UserID = TheUserID` lacks a `=`, as it is now it's an assignment

Comment: @Tobias: yes, was just a typo, fixed it; thanks.

Comment: If the `UserRecords` table contains to foreign keys, you will be able to remove the join from the LINQ query, which improves the readability of your code.

Comment: @frenchie regarding some of your questions to krizz: krizz is correct about his queryies only resulting in a single SQL server query.  One of the really great properties of LINQ is that the queries are composable.  That means that you can create a query, and then query the query.  So long as your initial query does not do something that causes an immediate execution (like calling ToList or ToArray), those queries will be composed into a single query at runtime.  This is extremely powerful, because it allows you to create utility functions that return query fragments.

Comment: @JMarsch: ok, thanks for the explanation; it makes sense to me too now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Anand, you will need a linq query:

```
var filterUserRecord = from u in MyDC.UserRecords
                       where u.UserID  == TheUserID
                       select u;

var q1 = from r in  MyDC.RecordsTable
          where r.RecordID = TheRecordID
          where filterUserRecord.Any(f => f.RecordID == r.RecordID)
          select r;
```

This will be converted to the SQL query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM RecordsTable rt WHERE rt.RecordID = TheRecordID AND EXISTS
   (SELECT recordId FROM UserRecords ur WHERE ur.userId = TheUserID AND ur.recordID = rt.recordID)
```

Note that those are `IQueryable<T>`s and linq queries on it will produce another `IQueryable<T>` which will contain expressions to be wholly translated to SQL (or whatever the backend is) instead of naively evaluating it at client side.

Comment: does my query as it is work? I don't want query all the records first and then just select one in a subquery; too slow.

Comment: The query I pasted above will first query records from RecordsTable with RecordID equal to TheRecordID and then apply subquery only for the found records to make sure user is authorized. It is not true that all records are queried.

Comment: Your query looks OK as well, but I think mine is a little bit more cleaner / easier to understand what it means. I am not that convinced that yours is much faster, but could be. I would do some tests.

Answer (score 3):

Well I think your problem could be solved by subquery

sql:

```
select * from RecordsTable where recordId in 
(select recordId from UserRecords where userId = @someUserId)
```

It could be represented in Linq as following

```
var filterUserRecord = from u in MyDC.UserRecords
                       where u.UserID  == TheUserID
                       select u

var q1 = from r in  MyDC.RecordsTable
         where filterUserRecord.Any(f => f.RecordID == r.RecordID)
```

Details for subquery in Linq - Read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979389/correlated-subquery-sql-to-linq)

Comment: no, that would require loading ALL the UserRecords first; too slow.

Comment: I don't think so, I think `Any` will be converted to SQL's `EXISTS()`. See my answer.

Comment: LINQ queries are evaluated lazily. So I do not think first filterUserRecord would be evaluated first and then it would be fed in to second query. For fetching the required data, you need to traverse both table once any how.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps read the article [here](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34653/1954) which discusses how SQL Injection (which I assume should be the main security concern here) is handled in LINQ scenarios.

There is also a nice article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760.aspx) regarding Microsoft's security considerations for EF. It's worth a read for anyone developing with these tools!

**[Edit]** With regards to your last comment, you can use queries similar to those already on this page. To condense a little: If your database is normalised, to the extent that the RecordId is a unique primary key, you can bypass joins to make a query which reads a little better:

```
var targetRecords = 
    from userRecords in MyDC.UserRecords
    where userRecords.UserTable.UserID == TheUserID
    && userRecords.RecordsTable.RecordID == TheRecord.RecordID
    select userRecords;

var targetRecordsResult = targetRecords.SingleOrDefault();
```

I have separated the query from it's result 'var' here to point out that 'targetRecords' does NOT get evaluated until you call SingleOrDefault on it in order to assign to targetRecordsResult. You can of course wrap this into one statement if you wish.

If, as mentioned, your RecordID is a Unique Primary Key, you will either get the matching Record back, or null. Note that if this isn't the case, i.e. more than on Record could have the same ID, then the SingleOrDefault call can fail. If your database is designed like that, you would have to use a query more like the one which Anand has specified. That is slightly more verbose, but will return you ANY Record with a matching id for that specific user.

In terms of security, note that your SQL statement will get compiled containing the UserID, making it very difficult to tamper with. Hence my point that in this case, the scope and exposure of UserID is your main concern. If, like you have stated, the user (and any potential malitious user) has no access to the variable (via property exposure etc) then this should be more than suitable for your needs.

Comment: Yes it does, but note that it is more verbose than it needs to be. It is effectively as secure as your TheUserId variable is. If that is controlled, and not exposed, than your query meets your security requirements. As others have pointed out, you don't require the manual joining, and can rely on using the defined relationship. That makes the query easier to understand. Also, note in krizz's comments: The query does NOT pull back all users, and LINQ queries won't by default in this case get executed at the time they are created. The means that the SQL generated is efficient, and secure.

Comment: ok, so what is your version of the query? In code. The UserID field is stored in the session and never sent to the client's page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var RecordToUpdate = (from u in MyDC.UserRecords
                      where u.UserTable.UserID == TheUserID
                      and u.RecordsTable.RecordID == TheRecord.RecordID).SingleOrDefault();
```

This will return the result for query which has specified UserID and RecordID.